# How can I put multiple canvas elements in to one canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have multiple canvas elements created by JavaScript. My question is: "How can I put multiple canvas elements to one canvas element?".

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/UqxCY/)

- It will grab each canvas and make them PNG's
- Access the buffer canvas and write the PNG's on top of each other inside it
- Write back the buffer canvas to PNG and send it to the IMG-tag

Just give the `#buffer` canvas element `display: none;` and everything will happen invisible (check here; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/UqxCY/2/).

**HTML**

```
<body onload="generatePNG()">
    <canvas id="c1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c3"></canvas>

    <canvas id="buffer"></canvas>

    <div id="output">Empty</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
canvas[id^=c], div[id=output] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

canvas[id=buffer] {
    border: 1px dotted green;
}

#output {
    padding: 15px;
}

#output img {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function generatePNG() {
    var b_canvas1 = document.getElementById("c1");
    var b_context1 = b_canvas1.getContext("2d");
    b_context1.fillRect(10, 50, 50, 50);
    var b_canvas2 = document.getElementById("c2");
    var b_context2 = b_canvas2.getContext("2d");
    b_context2.fillRect(80, 50, 50, 50);
    var b_canvas3 = document.getElementById("c3");
    var b_context3 = b_canvas3.getContext("2d");
    b_context3.fillRect(150, 50, 50, 50);

    var img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = b_canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
    var img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = b_canvas2.toDataURL("image/png");
    var img3 = new Image();
    img3.src = b_canvas3.toDataURL("image/png");

    var buffer = document.getElementById("buffer");
    var buffer_context = buffer.getContext("2d");
    buffer_context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    buffer_context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
    buffer_context.drawImage(img3, 0, 0);

    var buffer_img = new Image();
    buffer_img.src = buffer.toDataURL("image/png");

    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML = '<img src="' + buffer_img.src + '" alt="Canvas Image" />';
}
```

Comment: This works but you are using jquery. Is there a possibility doing it without the use of jquery?

Comment: Sure; the question is updated to now work fully on native JavaScript.

Comment: You don't need to create the intermediate images. The drawImage method can take another canvas directly as the image to draw.

Comment: @ChrisW. That's nice to know Chris. I never worked very thorough with canvas in the past, but that seems like a great skip-step to shorten the code and make it a bit lighter :)

Comment: @Allendar, the strange thing is that your native JavaScript code works in JSFiddle, but not in a real html document. Did you tested it in a real html document?

Comment: Try `<body onload="generatePNG()">` (without the closing semicolon).

Comment: If I do it like that, then only the 3 images are displayed, but the 3 images combined in the output part arent. 

I've tried also to do something like this:
`(function generatePNG() {
 //the code
})();`

But it also didn't work.

Comment: Are you using a doctype? `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Yes. But does the JavaScript code work on your computer system?

Comment: Yes it does. There might be some issues on different systems with the initial binding of the canvas to an image-hash tho, where it would only start to show up once the image is cached in the browser. Maybe there are some articles online to force the image in `<img>`-tag to force-show on the initial load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28600/discussion-between-julian-and-allendar)

Answer (score 2):

A canvas's drawImage method can actually take another canvas instead of an image - you don't need to convert the canvases to images first. (See the [WhatWG's documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#images).)

I've simplified Allendar's JSFiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/7hEKL/

Basically, all you need to do is:

```
targetCanvas.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0);
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this, export the source canvas to an image, paint that image to the target canvas (untested):

```
function drawCanvasOnOtherCanvas(src, target) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    target.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  };
  img.src = src.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```