# Merging multiple previous drawn canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In my current code I have different functions to draw different canvases, these work perfectly. The draw function will be called a number of times and store the result to be called later, once the image is finalised.

I cannot get the two images to merge together. I can redraw them individually in mergeCanvas(), by calling 'testbor1.url' but when I try to draw them onto a new canvas, the result is blank.

Can anyone tell me why I cannot draw these onto one canvas?

Following: [How can I put multiple canvas elements in to one canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082849/how-can-i-put-multiple-canvas-elements-in-to-one-canvas-element)

```
function draw()
{
    var can3 = document.getElementById('RugCanvas3');
    can3.offset = 0;
    can3.width = namespacetest.getCanvasWidth();
    can3.height = namespacetest.getCanvasHeight();

    var ctx3 = can3.getContext('2d');
    ctx3.drawImage(drawBorder(70,size,img, borderwidth), 0, 0);    
    ctx3.drawImage(drawOverlay(borderwidth, 70), 0, 0);  

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = can3.toDataURL("image/png");
    namespacetest.dataURLs['img1'] = img.src;
}

namespacetest.mergeCanvas = function()
{

   var testbor1 = new Image();
   var testbor2 = new Image();
   testbor1.src = namespacetest.dataURLs['img1'];
   testbor2.src = namespacetest.dataURLs['img2'];

   var bor = document.getElementById('Canvas5');
   var ctx = bor.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(testbor1, 0, 0, 400, 400);
   ctx.drawImage(testbor2, 0, 0, 400, 400);

   var buffer_img = new Image();
   buffer_img.src = bor.toDataURL("image/png");

   var output = document.getElementById('RugCanvas6');
   output.innerHTML = '<img src="' + buffer_img.src + '" alt="Canvas Image" />';

}
```

Comment: What are `drawBorder` and `drawOverlay` returning? Also, the accepted answer on the question you pointed to is awful: don't go through an Image to draw a canvas on an other, directly call `ctx.drawImage(canvasElement, x, y)`.

Comment: drawBorder & drawOverlay return an offscreen canvas, which is working. I will try what you suggested.

Comment: @Kaiido My fault, I wasn't setting a height & width for the new canvas. Thank you for your help.